# Type needs to conform to Encodable protocol even though it is already

Tags: swift, protocols, codable, encodable

Error:

> Instance method 'encodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)' requires that '[RelatedQuestions].Type' conform to 'Encodable'

The object i have already conforms to the `Codable` protocol and it is still giving me the error that it is not. Why?

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
        try container.encode(imgURL, forKey: .imgURL)
        try container.encode(thumbnail, forKey: .thumbnail)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(tweetText, forKey: .tweetText)
        try container.encode(content, forKey: .content)

        try container.encode(isDailyHidden, forKey: .isDailyHidden)
        try container.encodeIfPresent([Wisdom], forKey: .wisdom) //ERROR
        try container.encodeIfPresent(churchFather, forKey: .churchFather)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(popeSay, forKey: .popeSay)
        try container.encodeIfPresent([RelatedQuestions], forKey: .relatedIds) //ERROR
        try container.encodeIfPresent([Video], forKey: .video) // ERROR
}
```

Here is one of the models that conforms to `Codable`.

```
struct RelatedQuestions: Codable {
    let id: String
    let number, title, imgUrl, thumbnail: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, number, title, thumbnail
        case imgUrl = "img_url"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        number = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .number)
        imgUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .imgUrl)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        thumbnail = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
        try container.encode(imgUrl, forKey: .imgUrl)
        try container.encode(thumbnail, forKey: .thumbnail)

    }
}
```

I cleaned the build folder restarted Xcode. Same issue. What have i done wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I see. This is an obvious typo on your side.

`[RelatedQuestions]` is a type. It's not something to encode. You have to use the actual local variable, e.g. `self.relatedQuestions`.

Also note that your decoding and encoding functions are fairly simple and can be generated automatically, e.g. :

```
struct RelatedQuestions: Codable {
   let id: String
   let number, title, imgUrl, thumbnail: String

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id, number, title, thumbnail
      case imgUrl = "img_url"
   }
}
```

Actually, even the `CodingKeys` could be generated automatically.